# how make a current directory as home directory in linux

Tags: linux, slurm, singularity-container

please would you help me with your suggestions on the following :

<> I am using an account on a SLURM cluster where the storage space of my home directory (ie. /home/user) is maximum 32 GB

<> I am running on the SLURM cluster a singularity container that is working only if the the input files are located in the home directory (/home/user that has 32 GB), instead of using any other location on the SLURM cluster (i.e. /labs/professor where we have 7TB)

The question is : is there any way to set up the large account space (i.e. /labs/professor) as a "home directory" in order for the singularity container to run ?

thanks a lot, with much appreciation,

-- bogdan

Comment: Would a symlink be possible? Is the issue that the input files have to look like they are in home?

Comment: Or, depending on your privilege levels, a bind mount?  Or even using `sshfs` locally?

Comment: thank you very much for your quick replies; i will look into the documentation of "sshfs'". Any examples of how to use "sshfs" would be very welcome. Thanks again !

Comment: Well ... you'd create a new directory `newdir` in your home as a mount-point ... then `sshfs user@localhost:/labs/professor ~/newdir` ...

Comment: Dear Tink, thank you very much. Just to add a bit more information, please : both folders are on the SLURM cluster, i.e. /home/user and/labs/professor (i.e. /home user is not on a local machine that i use to access the SLURM cluster by ssh@network.edu). Shall i use  :  sshfs user@lnetwrok.edu:/labs/professor ~/example, the message i am getting is "fuse: bad mount point `/home/user/example': No such file or directory". Any suggestion is welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change variable `HOME` as you like (but i wont recommend that unless you know what things are gonna change)
But simpler way is to mane soft links for the directories you like, which i personally do.

```
ln -s path/of/dir path/to/dir
```

You can make or edit `user-dirs.dirs` file under `~/.config` directory to this

```
SECOND_HOME="/labs/professor"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Downloads"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Videos"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$SECOND_HOME/Public"
```

Here you can change default directories used by system. You can change your `SECOND_HOME` as you like

Edit:
If you want to change your default HOME then overwrite HOME variable on user login (it depends on which display manager you are using, but its easy)

But before that move every thing (ie. .config, .local, etc) directories to the directory which you want to set as HOME (eg. /labs/professor)

**Or** you can directly run

```
usermod -m -d /newhome/username username
```

Here -m (abbreviation for --move-home) will move the content from the user's current directory to the new directory.

Comment: Dear Rishav, thank you very much for your suggestions ! If I may ask you please, shall i setup a SECOND_HOME, will the singularity container process the files directly in the SECOND_HOME as the first choice, or will it still look into main home directory (ie /home/user), before depositing the output files and doing the computation in the SECOND_HOME (ie /labs/professor)? Or shall i set up ("labs/professor") as the MAIN_HOME, and the SECOND_HOME in "/home/user". Thanks again :)

Comment: Dear Rishav, thank you very much for your suggestions. I will talk with the IT folks that manage the SLURM cluster and confirm that it is ok by them to make the change and will implement your suggestion. Many thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

If you just want singularity to use somewhere else as `HOME`, you can set that via [command line](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/cli/singularity_exec.html#options).

```sh
singularity exec --help
# ...
# -H, --home string            a home directory specification.  spec can
#                               either be a src path or src:dest pair.  src
#                               is the source path of the home directory
#                               outside the container and dest overrides
#                               the home directory within the container.
#                               (default "$HOME")
# ...

singularity exec -H /labs/professor:/home ls -l /home
# will match
ls -l /labs/professor
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add a comment, and it was not formatted properly. If you do not mind, I will add it here :

i have got the pipeline to run in the following way :

```
singularity exec \
--bind /local/scratch/btanasa:/output8 \
--home /labs/jlgoldbe/MASSY_data_SLAMseq/the_SAMPLES_MAY2021:/home \
/labs/jlgoldbe/MASSY_data_SLAMseq/the_SAMPLES_MAY2021/SLAMDUNK_SINGULARITY/slamdunk_latest.sif slamdunk all \
-r GRCm38.primary_assembly.genome.fa \
-b 3UTRs_vM14_github_repository.27aug2020.sortdesc.LONG.with.SYMBOLS.to.use.bed \
-o /output8 \
-t 4 \
./8_R1_001.fastq.gz
```